# Background color not getting updated by updating CSS variables using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the JavaScript section, I have updated the variables such as spacing for padding, blur for making the image blur and basec for changing the background color of the image including the color of span tag in heading which is JS. **The background color of the image is not at all Updating.**
Rest All are working properly. Please look into the JavaScript section and please tell why basec variable is not changing.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');


function update() {
  // console.log(this.value);
  const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || '';
  // console.log(suffix);
  // console.log(this.name);
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);

}

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', update));
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemove', update));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

:root {
  --spacing: 10px;
  --blur: 1px;
  --basec: #ffe591;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.controls {
  margin: 40px;
}

img {
  padding: var(--spacing);
  filter: blur(var(--blur));
  background: var(--basec);
}

.h1 {
  color: var(--basec);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS variables updation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="controls.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Updating CSS variables using <span class="h1">JS</span></h2>

  <div class="controls">
    <label for="spacing">Spacing :</label>
    <input type="range" name="spacing" id="spacing" min="10" max="200" value="10" data-sizing="px">


    <label for="blur">Blur :</label>
    <input type="range" name="blur" id="blur" min="1" max="30" value="10" data-sizing="px">

    <label for="base">Base Color</label>
    <input type="color" name="base" id="base" value="#ffe591">
  </div>

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/500/500" alt="an image">

  <script src="cssvar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: typo: `basec` not `base` for the name of your color picker element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in variable name,
It has to be `base` but you have named it `basec` in css.

**Tip:** You would probably want to use `input` event rather than `change` for inputs as `change` event might not show live changes.

```js
const inputs=document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');


function update(){
    // console.log(this.value);
    const suffix=this.dataset.sizing || '';
    // console.log(suffix);
    // console.log(this.name);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`,this.value+suffix);

}

inputs.forEach(input=>input.addEventListener('input',update));
inputs.forEach(input=>input.addEventListener('mousemove',update));
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

:root{
    --spacing:10px;
    --blur:1px;
    --base:#ffe591;
}

body{
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
}

.controls{
    margin: 40px;
}

img{
    padding:var(--spacing);
    filter: blur(var(--blur));
    background: var(--base);
}

.h1{
    color:var(--basec);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS variables updation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="controls.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Updating CSS variables using <span class="h1">JS</span></h2>

    <div class="controls">
        <label for="spacing">Spacing :</label>
        <input type="range" name="spacing" id="spacing" min="10" max="200" value="10" data-sizing="px">


        <label for="blur">Blur :</label>
        <input type="range" name="blur" id="blur" min="1" max="30" value="10" data-sizing="px">

        <label for="base">Base Color</label>
        <input type="color" name="base" id="base" value="#ffe591">
    </div>
    
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/500/500" alt="an image">

    <script src="cssvar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```